# Is it possible not to use Explorer on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, qt, webbrowser-control, qwebview

I'm developing a web browser in the Visual Studio, but I don't want to use the default internet explorer. I have Qt so is there any way I can use Qt's safari?

Comment: It's not Safari, it's WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no builtin option for that, but there's an extention:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/233945ae-0b7b-47e7-9b02-c5a11798afb5